# Getting ENOENT error while downloading file

Tags: android

Trying to create an app that helps to download files. I click download button, then progress bar appears. It shows the progress. Then the progress bar finishes and I'm getting ENOENT error:

`E/Error:: /storage/emulated/0/logo.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`
`E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/logo.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Can not understand what's wrong with this code, I tested it on emulator and on a real device.

```
public class DownloadProgress extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnShowProgress;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ImageView my_image;

    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    private static String file_url = "http://idsp.ak.gov.ng/images/logo.png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);

        my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);

        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch (id){
            case progress_bar_type:
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

   class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute(){
           super.onPreExecute();
           showDialog(progress_bar_type);
       }

       @Override
       protected  String doInBackground(String... f_url){
           int count;
           try{
               URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
               URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
               connection.connect();

               int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

               InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

               String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
               String fileName = "/logo.png";
               File imageFile = new File(storageDir+fileName);
               OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

               byte data[] = new byte[1024];
               long total = 0;

               while((count = input.read(data)) != -1){
                   total += count;

                   publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                   output.write(data, 0, count);
               }
               output.flush();

               output.close();
               input.close();
           }catch (Exception e){
               Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
           }

           return null;
       }

       protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress){
           pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
           dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

           String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/logo.png";
           my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
       }
   }
}
```

Thank you for reading this post!

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

`/storage/emulated/0/logo.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

is the primary reason for your issues.

Since Android 6.0 (API level 23) you should not only declare

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but also [request it in run time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java):

> If your app needs a dangerous permission, you must check whether you
>   have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires
>   that permission. Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can
>   revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a
>   lower API level. So even if the app used the camera yesterday, it
>   can't assume it still has that permission today.

And take a look at [`DownloadManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) - it is a system service that handles long-running HTTP downloads.